# long term/short term risk factors using MVC 3.0 vs staying with .NET 4+?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, migration

With MVC4 already out in beta, what are the risk factors creating a rather large eCommerce site in MVC3? Will the community drop support for this version of the framework in the coming months/years? When using  .NET4+ it gives you the ability to update old code (or at least tries to,) but is it possible to upgrade from MVC3 to future iterations?

Comment: MVC4 is not out; it's only a developer preview.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MVC 4 isn't officially out, but it should be released pretty soon.

As for your concern, Microsoft does a good job with making sure each successive version of MVC is backwards compatible with the last.  For instance, I upgraded a project from MVC 2 to MVC 3 with no problems and virtually no code changes.

Investing time in developing an MVC 3 application won't be wasted, especially since the new features in MVC 4 aren't dramatic.

Comment: MVC3 will surely be supported, and actually we have a MVC2 project